# Select the earliest record for each person

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried a few solutions but can't quite get this to work.

Here's my table:

```
id,name,title,year
1,Bill,Apple Tree,2010
2,Bill,Cheese Factory,1998
3,Bill,Pie Shop,2005
4,Ted,Vegetable Path,2004
5,Ted,Fruit Farm,1984
6,Ted,Chocolate Factory,2010
7,Death,Pumpkin Patch,2017
8,Death,Nut Plant,2016
9,Death,Pasta Bar,2020
```

I would like to get the earliest `year` for each `title` for each `name`, so I'm expecting these results:

```
Bill,Cheese Factory,1998
Ted,Fruit Farm,1984
Death,Nut Plant,2016
```

But this is not getting me the results I need:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.title, MIN(t1.year)
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.name
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the earliest year?  Do you mean that you want to sort the data asending depends on year?

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try  `GROUP BY t1.name, t1.title` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `row_number()`

```
select name,title,year from
(
select *,row_number() over (partition by name order by year) as rn
 from tablename
)A where rn=1
```